# Subtract/find the difference between 2 data frames with different numbers of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, difference, subtraction

I'm relatively new to R and haven't been able to find anywhere that answers this query.

I have 2 dataframes with the same number of rows but different numbers of columns. I want to subtract the values in matching columns to identify the difference between the 2 dataframes.

For example, these 2 dataframes resemble the ones I am working with:

```
df1<-data.frame(Measure=rep("test",3),Filename=c("filename1","filename2","filename3"),Op1=c(79,72,95),Op2=c(NA,NA,5),Op3=c(75,64,66),Op4=c(86,71,58))

   Filename  Op1  Op2  Op3  Op4
1  filename1  79   NA   75   86
2  filename2  72   NA   64   71
3  filename3  95   5    66   58

df2<-data.frame(Measure=rep("test",3),Filename=c("filename1","filename2","filename3"),Op1=c(9,NA,5),Op4=c(80,70,50))

   Filename  Op1  Op4
1  filename1   9   80
2  filename2   NA  70
3  filename3   5   50
```

Currently I have a function that melts the 2 data frames and sums the data that looks like this:

```
CalcFunSum<-function(MeasureName,BoxNumbers){
  temp<-data.frame()
  for (i in BoxNumbers){
    data<-melt(BoxNumbers[i])
    temp<-temp %>% bind_rows(data)
  }
  temp<-cbind(Measure = MeasureName,dcast(temp,Filename~variable,sum,fill = 0))
  temp
}
```

So `CalcFunSum(test,c(df1,df2))` will add the 2 data frames together and produce

```
  Measure  Filename  Op1  Op2  Op3  Op4
1  test   filename1  88   NA   75   166
2  test   filename2  72   NA   64   141
3  test   filename3  100  5    66   108
```

What I want is something similar to perform the calculation df1-df2 to get:

```
  Measure  Filename  Op1  Op2  Op3  Op4
1  test   filename1  70   NA   75   6
2  test   filename2  72   NA   64   1
3  test   filename3  90   5    66   8
```

I've tried replacing the `sum` in the function with `diff` but that didn't work

Any ideas how to go about this?

edit - I realised the function included reference to a list I hold these data frames in and changed it.

**Follow up: dealing with NA values**

So the answers so far work, but on testing with my actual data I have noticed that in cases where df2 has an NA but df1 has a value the resulting output contains NA and not the value in df1. I'm going to change one of the values in df2 to NA to reflect this.

In the current answers by @akrun and @IceCreamToucan the output would be

```
  Measure  Filename  Op1  Op2  Op3  Op4
1  test   filename1  70   NA   75   6
2  test   filename2  NA   NA   64   1
3  test   filename3  90   5    66   8
```

I presume this is an NA.rm = T somewhere in the code, or I need to deal with the NA values earlier in the process, but it would be useful to know if there are tweaks to the answers that could sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with a join using `data,table`.  Get the column names common in both dataset (`intersect`) and remove the names that are not needed for comparison (`setdiff`)

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), c("Measure", "Filename"))
```

Then do a join `on` the 'Measure', 'Filename', get the values of the columns ('nm1') from 'df1' and the corresponding columns in 'df2'.  Here, it would be `i.` as 'df2' is in the `i`th position (a data.table follows the same format `[i, j, by]`.  By using `mget`, it returns the columns in a `list`, we get the difference (`-`) of both sets of columns with `Map` and update by assigning (`:=`) the values which would reflect in the original dataset ('df1')

```
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := Map(`-`, mget(nm1),
           mget(paste0("i.", nm1))), on = .(Measure, Filename)]
df1
#   Measure  Filename Op1 Op2 Op3 Op4
#1:    test filename1  70  NA  75   6
#2:    test filename2  70  NA  64   1
#3:    test filename3  90   5  66   8
```

#### Update

Any value compared with NA returns NA,  Similarly,

```
72-NA
#[1] NA
```

To avoid this issue, we can `replace` the `NA` with 0 and then do the difference

```
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := Map(function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), 0) - 
     replace(y, is.na(y), 0), 
    mget(nm1),mget(paste0("i.", nm1))), on = .(Measure, Filename)]

df1
#   Measure  Filename Op1 Op2 Op3 Op4
#1:    test filename1  70  NA  75   6
#2:    test filename2  72  NA  64   1
#3:    test filename3  90   5  66   8
```

Comment: That works nicely, thank you. I can just about follow your explanation too - I think! Anywhere I can look to get more information on what's happening here? Quick query - I note that this 'overwrites' the df1 frame with the output I want. How does assignment work here? do I df3 <- setDT(df1)... or can I do setDT(df3)... ?

Comment: @MWilding  I would use `copy` i.e. `df3 <- copy(df1)` and then work on `df3` because by doing a simple assignment to another identifier, the location is not going to change

Comment: @MWilding i.e `tracemem(df1)#
[1] "<0x7fca05e4b200>"
df3 <- df1;
tracemem(df3)
[1] "<0x7fca05e4b200>"`  Now, doing with `copy` `df3 <- copy(df1);tracemem(df1)
[1] "<0x7fca05e4b200>"
> tracemem(df3)
[1] "<0x7fca06cca000>"`

Comment: Sorry, I was just updating the question - there's an issue when df2 contains an NA but df1 has a value

Comment: @MWilding  Okay, understand the issue.  Can you try the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the update, I can confirm that this works. I think I might go back to the source data and deal with the NA values there though to avoid issues like this downstream.

Answer (score 3):

If you're comparing one row in `df1` to the same row in `df2`, i.e. matching indices and not checking for equality of some join column, you can just subtract `df2[common_columns]` from `df1[common_columns]` and assign the result back to `df1` (or a copy).

```
common <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))[-(1:2)]
new <- df1 # or copy(df1) if df1 is a data.table
new[common] <- df1[common] - df2[common]


new
#   Measure  Filename Op1 Op2 Op3 Op4
# 1    test filename1  70  NA  75   6
# 2    test filename2  70  NA  64   1
# 3    test filename3  90   5  66   8
```

---

Edit: 
If some values in `df2` are `NA` you can `replace` them with 0 before subtracting

```
common <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))[-(1:2)]
new <- df1
new[common] <- new[common] - replace(df2[common], is.na(df2[common]), 0)


new
#   Measure  Filename Op1 Op2 Op3 Op4
# 1    test filename1  70  NA  75   6
# 2    test filename2  72  NA  64   1
# 3    test filename3  90   5  66   8
```

Comment: If I understand this right, what you are doing is identifying the common column names containing the data, replicating the 'primary' dataframe and then for the identified common columns are performing the subtraction. I quite like this one :)

Comment: Yep, that's an accurate description

Comment: Please can you see the update to the question and see if you'd like to update the answer as a result?